# PubNub how the basic chat application can be configured ios

Tags: ios, swift, chat, pubnub

i'm new to PubNub [iOS], i see the tutorial videos and documentation, But i can't understand how the actual process happens
I understand this, We create [Pub/Sub] PubNub Channels to receive messages, but these channels are not stored any where in the pubnub, then how to manage an app like WhatsApp (Has groups and Single user chat)

Please suggest how to configure the existing iOS App for PubNub

As i understand
i need to create a separate channel for each friend of a user, 
and separate channel for each user in a group to group
is this correct?
or please explain the procedure how it should configure in my app

**Edit:**

I have a question regarding storing and retrieve messages from history

In Case of single user chat:

When `User1` sendMessage to `User2`, i'm Publishing in Two channel as per the [Inbound Architecture](http://scalabl3.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/03/05/Inbound-Channel-Pattern.html) in the `scalabl3`

1. inbound_user2
2. hybrid_user1_to_user2

When `User2` sendMessage to `User1`, i'm publishing in Two channel

1. inbound_user1
2. hybrid_user2_to_user1

But when i've to retrieve the history i need to get history from two channels `hybrid_user1_to_user2` and `hybrid_user2_to_user1` and need to sort them by timetoken

Can you please tell me that is it is the correct approach or not?
if not please suggest

Thanks...

Comment: Channels are lightweight - you publish to them and you subscribe to them and they exist as they are used. A channel for each user is typical use case as a private channel for sending messages that are only meant for that user (inbox channel), like invites or notifications. A channel for each 1-1 chat and 1 channel for each group chat is also typical. You will likely keep track of these channels somehow on your end (log them to your server DB, locally in each client, etc). If you have a real project, contacting PubNub Support to get on a call with a Customer Success Manager to get started.

Comment: i found this, please check [here](http://scalabl3.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/03/05/Inbound-Channel-Pattern.html)

Comment: Yes, *scalabl3* is a PubNub Solution Architect. Did you have questions about his design pattern?

Comment: @CraigConover, thanks for you response, I updated the question with my doubts, can you please check once

Comment: There are advantages and disadvantages to using a two channel chat design pattern. The disadvantage, is as you point out, you have to get history from two channels and stitch the messages together sorted by timetoken. But yes, that is the right thing to do.

Comment: @CraigConover, thanks, Can i use same architecture for the GroupChat also, Subscribe to Each group Inbound channel and get history for each user hybrid channel `(group_1_user_1, group_1_user_2)` in group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have just one unique hybrid channel that both publish to?

When User1 sendMessage to User2, publish to:

1. inbound_user2
2. hybrid_user1_user2

When User2 sendMessage to User1, publish to:

1. inbound_user1
2. hybrid_user1_user2

Each user is subscribed to their own inbound channel, and uses the shared hybrid channel to obtain complete history.

Comment: When we are getting the history from that hybrid channel `hybrid_user1_user2` we only get messages and timetokens, so we cannot distinguish which message is sent by `User2` and `User1`, so i'm using this to distinguish the messages from different users

Comment: When you publish a message, include in the payload a key:value pair identifying the sender

Comment: but additional payload is not available in history call for me, can you please explain more about this

Comment: @rak when the user first publishes the message, include in the original 32kb JSON payload an additional key value pair 'senderID: user 1'

Comment: thanks @Alex, i will try this & update you with the results